# Gracefull termination of multiprocessing.Pool.map function using KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool, termination

I'm trying to terminate gracefully `Pool.map()` function using `KeyboardInterrupt`.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time


def func(num):
    try:
        while True:
            print(f'Process num {num}')
            time.sleep(30)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f'Process {num} was interrupted')
    finally:
        print('Cleaning up the thread')


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    try:
        pool.map(func, range(9))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Main process was interrupted)
        pool. Close()

    finally:
        print('Cleaning up main')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While it works fine with `range(8)` (cuz I have 8 logical cores and only 8 processes running simultaneously). After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I receive the following output:

```
python experiment.py

Process num 0
Process num 1
Process num 2
Process num 3
Process num 4
Process num 5
Process num 6
Process num 7
Process 7 was interrupted
Process 6 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Process 4 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Process 5 was interrupted
Process 3 was interrupted
Process 2 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Process 0 was interrupted
Process 1 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Main process was interrupted
Cleaning up main
```

However, when I use `range(9)`, after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it interrupts only 8 processes that are already running, while `map` function keeps on running generating a new process, and after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> once again I get the following output:

```
Process num 0
Process num 1
Process num 2
Process num 3
Process num 4
Process num 5
Process num 6
Process num 7
Process 6 was interrupted
Process 7 was interrupted
Process 5 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Process 2 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Process 3 was interrupted
Process 1 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Process 0 was interrupted
Process num 8
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Process 4 was interrupted
Cleaning up the thread
Cleaning up the thread
Process 8 was interrupted
Process SpawnPoolWorker-7:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-6:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-5:
Cleaning up the thread
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-1:
Main process was interrupted
Cleaning up main
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zamotory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self. Run()
```

Is there any way to stop `Pool.map()` after the single press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?